# Why doesn't the git flow release finish command do its job completely?

Tags: git, git-flow

As explained [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), Git flow's `release finish` does two things -

1. Merging the release branch into the development branch, and
2. Deleting itself.

But since it is a `release` branch, shouldn't it also be merged to the master branch before it gets deleted?

Why do we have to merge it to master manually before doing a `git flow release finish ...`?

Answer (score 2):

In this [git flow cheatsheet](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/#release), the merge to master is included in `git flow release finish`

[image: git flow release finish]

> - Merges the release branch back into 'master'
> - Tags the release with its name
> - Back-merges the release into 'develop'
> - Removes the release branch

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem with Atlassian. I checked it [here](https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac) as well and it seems this is just a stupid question I got from reading the wrong material. Thanks!